# Console text editor with "Windows-like" shortcuts (CTRL+A, -C, -X, -V, Shift+End, Shift+Up ...)

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, text-editor

I have used Windows for ~30 years and I remember its shortcuts well. I have used Ubuntu for about 5 years and never remember its shortcuts. I do not use text editors all the time, so most likely I will not remember the shortcuts of say `Vi` or `Nano`. I am a teacher and use lots of different consoles in different computers, so one configuration of say `Emacs` will not do it. I have this problem few times a month and have had it for about the 5 years I've used Ubuntu and not yet found a suitable program. Most usual use cases are commanding a server via ssh or solving a problem with a crashed GUI.

So is there a console text editor for Ubuntu with "Windows-like" shortcut keys:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select all
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy,
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> cut,
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste,
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> undo,
- <kbd>END</kbd> go to end of line,
- <kbd>HOME</kbd> go to beginning of line,
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> go to beginning of file,
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> go to END of file,
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> skip word,
- Selecting text with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and moving cursor
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> save file

Most of these also work here in this platform independent StackExchange question editor, so this is not a "Windows only thing" actually.

Comment: May I ask why are you seeking console text editor with Windows graphical editors' shortcut? Those shortcuts even don't work in Windows cmd .

Comment: Commanding a server or solving a problem with a crashed GUI.

Comment: So, it is wrong to praise MS for providing easy shortcuts while actually they didn't, for command line editors. In fact, MS even doesn't have a good command line editor like vim and emacs in Unix world.

Comment: Where do I praise MS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FTE Text Editor](http://fte.sourceforge.net/) is a good choice for windows like shortcut like `shift + down` key for text selection, `Ctrl+z` for undo, `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`.

Installs with `sudo apt install fte` and runs with `fte`

It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not a _console_ editor, though.

Comment: @AlexP edited my answer.

Comment: Though I doesn't have `Ctrl+S` for saving. Anyway better than the original gedit suggestion

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Installs with sudo apt install fte and runs with fte, so I can use this in seconds.

Comment: @OhtoNordberg I am glad you find it useful. I'll add your installation command in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiflo](https://gitlab.com/mattmaniak/fiflo) seems fine. It doesn't have all of above shortcuts but some of them.